# Python kivy for cross-platform apps

Tags: python, ios, windows, kivy, cross-platform

Good day
I want to build cross-platform mobile app with python kivy.The problem is that I don't have mac to test project on ios emulator.Do you have any idea.Or can i just test it only on android phone and will it work the same in iphone?

Answer (score 0):

i have used kivy before, sometimes the code runs well on a platform don't guarantee that it will do the same in another, so it is always a good practice to test your app on both platform. if you don't have access to a mac, i recommend you using services such as [MacInCloud](https://www.macincloud.com) [VirtualMacOSX](http://virtualmacosx.com) [XCodeClub](https://xcodeclub.com) or other alternatives to test and build your app for ios. (if you are lucky you may find free trial on some of the alternatives)